# multiple items in ItemsControl on a Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, itemscontrol

In the XAML below, please fill in the "WhatGoesHere" node and explain to me how that won't mess up the coordinates on the `Canvas`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WhatGoesHere?>
                <Path Stroke="CornflowerBlue" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures2}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </WhatGoesHere?>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My example has two of the same type of object in the template, but I will have several other control types in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than one element within a `DataTemplate`.  You would have to put your two `Path` objects into some kind of `Panel`, like for example a `Grid`. The question is where are all your the canvas coordinates computed so that you can bind the `Grid` to it? In your view model? Then you could bind to it and it could look somewhat like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" Canvas.Left="{Binding X}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Path Stroke="CornflowerBlue" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures2}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In case you do not have these coordinates, then I would recommend to use another value for `ItemsPanelTemplate` like a `VirtualizedStackPanel`. This might look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizedStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Path Stroke="CornflowerBlue" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures2}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you could tell me what your actually trying to achieve, I'm sure I can help you in a better way.

Comment: I was thinking that I was going to have some canvas elements, but after looking at your example I see that I need a second ItemsControl inside my template where I include my canvas items.